# phpass CheckPassword function always returns false, while trying to login. Newbie issue

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords, phpass

Been trying to find solution in forums, and in stack's questions, but no results so you are my last hope. I'm using phpass for password encryption, sign up script works just fine, but when I try to login and use CheckPassword function it always returns false. I'm adding my both php scripts:

SIGN UP:

```
 <?php 
 require 'phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php';
 require 'config.php';

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $confirmed_email = $_POST['confirmed_email'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];



 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

 if(!preg_match("^[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9,!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^_`\{\|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,})$^", $email))
 {
    $errors[] = "Incorrect email format.";
 }

 if (($email)!==($confirmed_email))
 {
    $errors[] = "Emails do not match";
 }


 if ((strlen($username) < 5) || (!ctype_alnum($username)))
 {
    $errors[] = "Username must be min 6 signs and only include 0-9, A-Z characters.";
 }

 if ((strlen($password) < 7) || (!ctype_alnum($password)))
 {
    $errors[] = "Password must be min 8 signs and only include 0-9, A-Z characters.";
 }

 $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1');
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();

 if($stmt->num_rows == 1)
 {
    $errors[] = "Username is taken.";
 }


 else if (!count($errors)) {
 $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
 $hash = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
 if (strlen($hash) >= 20) {
 $stmt = $db->prepare('insert into users (username, email, password) values (?, ?, ?)');
 $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $hash);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 $db->close();
     }
 }

   Foreach($errors as $v) print "$v <br/>";
 }

 ?>
```

LOGIN:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
require 'phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php';

if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) { 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];




 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); 
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $hash);
 $stmt->fetch();

 $stored_hash = $hash;
 $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);


 $check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash);

 if ($check) {

 echo"Logged IN"; 

 } else {

 echo "SOMETHING'S WRONG";
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Please, do not pay attention to security issues, cause it's just a demo scripts and I'm still learning.

Comment: **TL;DR**. Try making your question more concise. If we need more, we'll ask.

Comment: What does `var_dump($hasher->CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash));` output? It seems like nothing is being assigned to your `$check` variable.

Comment: @AmalMurali yap, bool(false)

Comment: So something's is not right with CheckPassword function?

Comment: @user2699508 - I would do the var_dump also with the parameters `$password` and `$stored_hash`, or even better install a debugger, it will help you many times in future. It is unlikely that CheckPassword() doesn't work, but often the $stored_hash is not the same as you stored, because the database field is too small to hold the whole string. Check what $stored_hash you stored, how it looks in the database, and how you got it back from the database.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the hashed password is 60 character, anything more will return false.
I have the same issue and notice my first hashed password was 61 characters.